# NTLM hash - change password and return the hash back

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, hash, ntlm

I'm working on a new project that would greatly help to those who have little brothers,

I thought about this idea:

Get the NTLM hash of the user, **write the hash into a text file**.

**Change** the password of the user `(cmd.exe /c net user %username% 123)`.

After that the password has been changed you can enter the account.

I don't want that somebody knew that I visited on the account
(someone can see that I changed His password)

**The idea is:**

open the `sam` file and **write back the old hash**

(**replace** the **new** hash that created by changing password with the **old** hash that i saved in text file.)

it means that I don't have to crack the password

1.save hash into text file.

2.change the password of the user.

3.enter the account.

4.write saved hash back into sam file (replace old with new)

5.Which means that I should not have to crack the hash just write it back.

code(only to explain):

```
Dim un As String = Environment.UserName 'UserName

Dim Hash As String = GetNtlmPass(un) 'Get Ntlm Hash By username

Shell("cmd.exe /c net user %username% 123") 'Change the password of current user

WaitCmdDone() 'Waiting until the password is changed.

PutNtlmHashBack(un,Hash) 'put the hash back by user name - This function is not exist!.
```

PutNtlmHashBack function is not exist

there is a function like `PutNtlmHashBack`?

i just need to write ntlm hash into sam file.

i can read all ntlm hashes by `pwdump.exe`, if i can read it so i can write to.

Comment: You could always use `runas` to run a program (e.g. a shell) under a different user's account...

Comment: the most comfortable way is to enter into the account